# Redirect to a controller using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I am trying to redirect to a controller using an external js file so that my url address bar will look like

"http://example.com/project/index.php/TravellerController/create/1".

**Javascript Code**:

```
u55.style.cursor = 'pointer';
$axure.eventManager.click('u55', function(e) {
 if (true) {
  self.location.href=$axure.globalVariableProvider.getLinkUrl('TravellerController');
 }
});
```

**u55** is the `id` of the link in my "home" views  file.

**TravellerController**:

```
<?php
class TravellerController extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $data=$this->get_data();
    }
    function get_data(){
        //*some code...*
        redirect('TravellerController/create/'.$data);
    }
    function create(){
        //*some code...*
    }
}
?>
```

So, if I click on that link my url looks like this:

"http://example.com/project/index.php/home/create/TravellerController"

But I want it like this:

"http://example.com/project/index.php/TravellerController/create/1"

Comment: You're recreating the exact functionality of a link to begin with, why are you trying to do it through JS when you can just alter the HREF of the anchor? Also, we have no way of knowing what your JS functions are doing, so we can't explain why your URLs are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $id = 1; //or somenthing else ?>

<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php echo site_url('travellercontroller/create/'.$id); ?>'"></a>
```